# Scrapy: How to get items that has been posted in the past 24 hours in an if statement?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi I wanted to filter my item using if statement, I just need to get the item that has been posted in the past 24 hours

Here's my code

```
#date where the item is posted
datime = response.css("a.datePermalink abbr::text").extract_first()
datime = datime.replace('at', '')
datime = parser.parse(datime)

if now-timedelta(hours=24) <= datime:
```

URL: https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/threads/tesla-tsla-the-investment-world-the-2019-investors-roundtable.139047/page-2440

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `datetime.timedelta` that you can get with subtraction of one `datetime` and another:

```
from dateparser import parse
from datetime import datetime

datime = response.css("a.datePermalink abbr::text").get()
datime = datime.replace('at', '')
datime = parse(datime)

if (datetime.now() - datime).total_seconds() // 3600 < 24:
    # do what you need
```

- `datetime.now()` is current `datetime`.
- `(datetime.now() - datime)` is `timedelta` that has `days`, `minutes` and `seconds`.
- `(datetime.now() - datime).total_seconds() // 3600` converts this timedelta from seconds to hours.

UPD: as @Jon Clements suggested, also valid:

```
if datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=25) <= datime:
```

Comment: You don't really need to jump through so many hoops here... the OP looks to already be going in the right direction. Also note, that the `.seconds` attribute isn't what you want to use here... try `timedelta(hours=25).seconds` for instance... to make your calculations work as expected you want to be using: `.total_seconds()`...

Comment: Yes, agree, good ideas. Was confused with misreading `now-timedelta` as some pseudo function name. Thank you!